# jquery : event : event.preventDefault(); , e is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

hey i have a jquery function that is triggered on an anchor's onclick event the function is as follows:

```
function dropDown(subid, e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var sub = '#' + subid;
 // hide all submenus first
 $('.subnav').css({'display' : 'none'});
 //Show the Current Subnav 
 $(sub).css({'display' : 'block'});
}
```

this is how i am tring to trigger it :

```
<a href="#!" onclick="dropDown('sn_cities')" >Cities</a>
```

However i am getting this error: `e is undefined`

i want to cancel the default onclick event of the anchor link, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not passing the event object (or anything at all) to the `e` parameter of the function. Try this:

```
onclick="dropDown('sn_cities',event);"
```

I'd be inclined to lose the inline JS altogether though:

```
<a href="#!" data-dropDown="sn_cities">Cities</a>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[data-dropDown]").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // hide all submenus first
       $('.subnav').hide();
       //Show the Current Subnav 
       $('#' + $(this).attr("data-dropDown")).show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropDown(subid) {
 var sub = '#' + subid;
 // hide all submenus first
 $('.subnav').css({'display' : 'none'});
 //Show the Current Subnav 
 $(sub).css({'display' : 'block'});
}

<a href="#!" onclick="dropDown('sn_cities'); return false;" >Cities</a>
```

As a side note. Inline-javascript is not recommended. Keep your scripts in an external file for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your response will try that now, just curious, is it not possible to pass other parameters with event in jquery ?

Comment: you can, as nnnnnn has posted also.

Comment: He call preventDefault to prevent a anchor to trigger and jump to a "#" link, you just simply remove that?

Comment: `return false;` is the equivalent of `preventDefault();` and `stopPropagation();`